# OpenDocument used from BI launchpad does not access current user session

Tags: business-objects, session-management, opendocument

Issue:

- A Dashboard (created in SAP Dashboards) has URL Buttons set up with OpenDocument URLs as links.
- When this ‘landing page dashboard’ is opened from the BI Launchpad (whether it’s saved as your default/home page or accessed directly from the platform file structure)… it requires additional authentication to follow an OpenDocument URL.  Regardless of file type, Webi documents, or other dashboard files.
- Not all users experience this issue, but at least ½ do.  Need to understand the difference in behavior and the root cause of it to advise fix.

Referencing OpenDocument user session documentation, there are workarounds with tokens and serialized sessions, but what other settings come into play to explain that only half of the users are impacted and prompted when using native functionality from launchpad?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24700775/3165737) SO question.

Answer (score 1):

One *possible* reason for this behavior is that the domain of the BO server as displayed in the address bar of the browser is different from the domain in the openDocument link.

For example, after logging in to BI launch pad, the browser displays the following in the address bar:

```
http://bi4server.company.com/BOE/BI
```

but the openDocument link is:

```
http://bi4server/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc.....
```

In this case, the domain is different so the original session isn't recognized.  If this is the case, the easiest solution is to remove the protocol and domain values from the URL, so that it begins with:

```
/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc.....
```